# Can't override a method of a controls

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, overriding

I am making a custom controls for silverlight 5, based on a controls AutoCompleteBox.

The thing is, , It seems, I have problems orreideing one of the methods.

`OnDropDownClosing`event, make the program does not build and raise an error `cannot found customclass namespace` .

I search and I think iI well override it :

The class

```
namespace myApp.myCustomControls
public class AutoCompleteBox : System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox

  {
        protected override void OnDropDownClosing(RoutedPropertyChangingEventArgs<bool> e)
            {
            }
  }
```

I do like this :

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="myApp.Views.View"
xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:myApp.myCustomControls">

...

    <myControl:AutoCompleteBox Name="myAcp"
                               .../>
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't know why, while other method like `OnDropDownClosed` and others works.

And when I comment the method that doesn't work, it build and run perfectly. It meens that is the ovveriding that is bugging. But why?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show more of the code, specifically where you are using customclass namespace.

Comment: Add the code. The thing that it must be understand is, when I comment the method, I can build correctly and run the app.

Comment: Ok, and what about the namespace of the class in the .cs ?

Comment: Add it but nothing special. Because it works when I remove the bugged method. It must be a problem with the method itself am I wrong?